# Placeholder won't disappear after I start typing yet placeholder for message does disappear

Tags: html, input, placeholder

When I start typing into my placeholder it doesn't disappear.

Everything was OK on desktop version of the site, until I've added this line of code for each section - I had to add it because without it when I checked the site via phone there was no placeholders at all (all label classes had no placeholder):

```
<span class="_placeholder" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 0px; height: 0px;">Telefón</span>
```

It worked fine on desktop when the code looked like this:

```
<label class="phone">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Telefón" data-constraints="@Required @Pattern(regex=/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/)"/>
    <span class="empty-message">*Prosím vyplňte toto pole.</span>
    <span class="error-message">*Znaky, ktoré ste zadali sú nečitateľné.</span>
</label>
```

But without span class="_placeholder" it looked like this [phone-no-placeholder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvwFE.jpg)

I will be waiting, hope someone can help :) 
link to the problem: http://eufrazia.sk/sitex/kontakt.html

Comment: *For the next bus to Peru Sam* @JayBlanchard

Comment: *It's going to be a long ride Ralph.* @Fred-ii-

Comment: *Llamas are quite patient and strong Sam, as am I. You know... the "cactus" thing!?* @JayBlanchard

Comment: _Sorry I cannot wait_ `<input>`'s can have placeholders `<span>`'s Cannot

Comment: I don't know what is the idea to have two `<span>` for each field, but simply remove the value into first span (as is for textarea).

Comment: I'm glad you're having fun :) Thanks I'm gonna try that.

Comment: Well I'm back at start. It works as it should on desktop, but when you check the page with phone the placeholders are well "out-of-place" any idea why this is ? I don't think it has anything to do with css...

Comment: "Well I'm back at start." - I.e. back to having only an input filed with a placeholder attribute; and no additional overlaying span element? Which browser (and version) do you use on the phone ("real" phone or simulator?) Compare to http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder . And btw: Why is this question marked as "php"?

Comment: I'm using Chrome. It looks like this when I check it via phone.

http://imgur.com/OvMR0sj

Comment: Let's start reeeeeally simple: http://pastebin.com/H4iJfaKa . It's working as expected on my android phone using chrome 48.0.2564.... Is _that_ working on your phone, too? When you type `about:` into the navigation/url bar, which chrome version does it show?

Comment: version: 47.0.2526.83

I asked a friend to check it with his Iphone 6s and he's getting the same problem as I do - the placeholders on mobile phone are below the whole section

Comment: "the placeholders on mobile phone are below the whole section" - for exactly the document that I've pasted to pastebin?

Comment: You are able to see for yourself when you check the site: http://eufrazia.sk/sitex/kontakt.html

Just open the --sekcie-- menu and then /kontakt/ - I'm sure you will see the placeholders out of place as well

Comment: http://pastebin.com/H4iJfaKa <- when you put _that_ document on a server and request it with your phone, does it look as and work as expected?

Comment: yes, it does work proper

Comment: It didn't really help though :/

Comment: I don't think you should add the `<span class="_placeholder"` element yourself. It looks like it should be a result of a polyfill of your framework/libraries. But how this works: I don't know; ask someone who knows template monster and TMForm.js in particular.

Comment: Will do. Thank you for your time. Have a nice day mate